# Simple Java echo server issue

Tags: java, sockets, client, echo

I'm trying to write my first socket server so I decided to start with something very simple be fore that just to figure the flow :) I'm writing a simple java echo server, but the thing is that (for some reason?!) I'm not getting the server response in the client, althought the request is received in the server.

```
package poc.client;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.Socket;

public class Client {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            final Socket socket = new Socket((String) null, 50000);

            final BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
            final PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(
                    socket.getOutputStream(), true);
            writer.println("ala bala\r\n");
            writer.flush();
            writer.close();

            System.out.println(reader.readLine());
            System.out.flush();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
                Logger.getAnonymouseLogger().throwing(TAG, "main", ex);
        }

    }
}
```

And the server part is

```
package poc.server;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

public class Server {

    /**
     * debugging purposes only
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private static final String TAG = Server.class.getSimpleName();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            final ServerSocket socket = new ServerSocket(50000);
            while (true) {
                final Socket clientSocket = socket.accept();
                final BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                        new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
                final PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(clientSocket
                        .getOutputStream(), true);

                writer.println(reader.readLine());
                writer.flush();
                writer.close();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
                Logger.getAnonymouseLogger().throwins(TAG, "main",ex);
        }

    }
}
```

I read all the Oracle basic socket tutorials/etc but I just can't figure what's wrong - I'm successfully writing to the server socket but I seem to be unable to get the response.

Comment: You should not ignore exceptions. That's like trying to drive a car with a blindfold on.

Comment: I'm not seeing anywhere in your server code where you're getting the client's IP address.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels as suggested by the package name this is PoC and not real code. Thanks for the advice, though.

Comment: @ChadM what do I need this address for?

Comment: I believe you need it so as to where to know where to return the response.

Comment: @ChadM: can you show a tutorial or documentation that backs up your recommendation because I don't think your statement is correct? All the server need do is accept the connection, and we know already that it's doing that.

Comment: @asenovm, did you try printing the exception traces if any ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not close the writer before reading from the socket. Following code works

```
final Socket socket = new Socket((String) null, 50000);

            final BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
            final PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(
                    socket.getOutputStream(), true);
            writer.println("ala bala\r\n");

            System.out.println(reader.readLine());            
            //writer.flush();
            writer.close();
```

As per the javadoc of close() method:

> Closes the stream and releases any system resources associated with
>   it. Closing a previously closed stream has no effect.

Looks like if you close the stream, the underlying socket also gets closed. You can verify this by printing the stack trace in your current code. It gives `java.net.SocketException: socket closed` error.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
Socket socket = new Socket(InetAddress.getLocalHost(), 50000);
```

Also note that, there is no need for `writer.flush();` since you are making it an auto-flush stream when you pass `true` to the second parameter of the `PrintWriter` constructor.

Comment: same :/ Thanks for the flush note, just wanted to be sure that it's not because of not flushing the stream. I'm able to write to the server socket(If I log reader.readLine() in the server this will give correct result, so the socket is correctly created. I'm unable to get the response - the client gets terminated after sending the request.

Comment: @asenovm Does it return from the method `readLine()` in `System.out.println(reader.readLine());`, i.e does it print anything on the console?